# "The software is not from a trusted source" when updating Operating System from AppCenter

Tags: release-loki, updates, appcenter

I received this message when updating Operating System from the AppCenter. How could this update not be from a trusted source? Could it be that my AppCenter has been compromised?[image: Dialog window in question]

Comment: You probably added a ppa that's not secure so unless you are sure it's safe to update don't do it. Delete such PPA if you think it's not safe

Comment: any news? I've the same problem..

Comment: Maccer was right, I added the Arc GTK repo without adding the key. After importing the key, the error was fixed.

Comment: how can I add the key? I'm a bit new on Linux..

Answer (score 1):

There is a repository key missing. To fix this, you can add the key in a terminal window with the following command:

```
wget --quiet http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```